# loopback 4 use middleware prometheus-api-metrics

Tags: node.js, prometheus, loopback4

How can I use the [prometheus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prometheus-api-metrics)  within a LoopBack 4 application

here is a piece of code from the application.ts file

```
export class BackendV4Application extends BootMixin(ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication))) {
```

constructor(options?: ApplicationConfig)
{

```
options = { ...options, rest: { requestBodyParser: { json: { limit: '6mb' } } } };

super(options);



// Set up dotenv
dotenv.config();

// Set up the base path
this.basePath('/api');

this.api({
  openapi: '3.0.0',
  info: { title: pkg.name, version: pkg.version },
  paths: {},
  components: { securitySchemes: SECURITY_SCHEME_SPEC },
  servers: [{ url: '/api' }]
});

this.setUpBindings();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a component package `@loopback/metrics` made by LoopBack that implements Prometheus. The [Metrics collection for Prometheus](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Metrics.html) documentation page explains how to set it up in the application.

Comment: hello this module is still in the testing phase

Comment: @AmiIne It does say so indeed, but it works quite well! Also, you can use the source code (https://github.com/loopbackio/loopback-next/tree/master/extensions/metrics) as a starting point for your own implementation and extend/improve it from there.